# replace words with images chatroom

Tags: javascript

Okay, below I have attached my chatroom script, What I'm trying to implement is a script which replaces specific words like `:wow` with an image `<img src="wow.gif"></img>` I previously used the following to achieve this;

`var newdata = data.replace(/:wow/g,"<img src=\"wow.gif\"></img>");`

however where I've recently redone my chatroom javascript I don't know where to place this or if this would even work with my updated script. Below is the JavaScript that loads my chatroom. Thankyou for any help.

```
var instanse = false;
var state;
var mes;
var file;

function Chat () {
    this.update = updateChat;
    this.send = sendChat;
    this.getState = getStateOfChat;
}

//gets the state of the chat
function getStateOfChat(){
    if(!instanse){
         instanse = true;
         $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "/_account/_pages/chat_room_scripts/process.php?room=<? echo $room; ?>",
               data: {  
                        'function': 'getState',
                        'file': file
                        },
               dataType: "json",

               success: function(data){
                   state = data.state;
                   instanse = false;
               },
            });
    }    
}

//Updates the chat
function updateChat(){
     if(!instanse){
         instanse = true;
         $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "/_account/_pages/chat_room_scripts/process.php?room=<? echo $room; ?>",
               data: {  
                        'function': 'update',
                        'state': state,
                        'file': file
                        },
               dataType: "json",
               success: function(data){
                   if(data.text){

                       for (var i = 0; i < data.text.length; i++) {
                            $('#chat-area').append($("<p>"+ data.text[i] +"</p>"));
                        }                                 
                   }
                   document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollTop = document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollHeight;
                   instanse = false;
                   state = data.state;
               },
            });
     }
     else {
         setTimeout(updateChat, 1500);
     }
}

//send the message
function sendChat(message, nickname)
{       
    updateChat();
     $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/_account/_pages/chat_room_scripts/process.php?room=<? echo $room; ?>",
           data: {  
                    'function': 'send',
                    'message': message,
                    'nickname': nickname,
                    'file': file
                 },
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(data){
               updateChat();
           },
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your update is referencing the chat content within an array of string data, in which case you'll reference `data.text[i]` within the `for` loop.  Try this:

```
//Updates the chat
function updateChat(){
     if(!instanse){
         instanse = true;
         $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "/_account/_pages/chat_room_scripts/process.php?room=<? echo $room; ?>",
               data: {  
                        'function': 'update',
                        'state': state,
                        'file': file
                        },
               dataType: "json",
               success: function(data){
                   if(data.text){

                       for (var i = 0; i < data.text.length; i++) {
// UPDATE HERE              
                            $('#chat-area').append($("<p>"+ data.text[i].replace(/:(wow|hi)/g,"<img src=\"$1.gif\"></img>")+"</p>"));
// UPDATE HERE
                        }                                 
                   }
                   document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollTop = document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollHeight;
                   instanse = false;
                   state = data.state;
               },
            });
     }
     else {
         setTimeout(updateChat, 1500);
     }
}
```

#### General Purpose Replacement

You can customize your emoticons by just adding them to the capture group separated by pipes:

```
replace(/:(wow|hi|fish|tiger|dog|elephant|bird)/g,"<img src=\"$1.gif\"></img>")
```

Comment: Thankyou that worked perfectly I'm really sorry I know I should have had this in the main question, If not its okay and I will still mark your question as the answer but is it possible for you to provide an example where this is used twice for example both the :wow and :hi changes to wow.gif and hi.gif so I can use this script for multiple words. Thankyou so much Cam

Comment: @Lewis, the code above has been updated to show how you can customize your emoticons.  It can all be handled through regex... the `$1` references the text captured by the `()` capture group.

Answer (score 0):

option 1:
if you want the code in the javascript, then in updateChat() where you are appending the html to #chat-area you could apply the same code. eg:

```
var newdata = data.replace(/:wow/g,"<img src=\"wow.gif\"></img>");
$('#chat-area').append($("<p>"+ newdata  +"</p>"));
```

option 2: 
do the replacement in the server side AJAX code.  This way you don't have to keep updating javascript to add new image translations.
And don't hardcode them, store the translations in a db table or file so you can easily add new ones.